# How to specify multiple type for delegate reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates

I have two problems in swift
1. Specifying multiple type for a delegate
2. Specifying a type for a delegate

```
id<MyProtocol, MyAnotherProtocol> delegate;
UIViewController<MyProtocol> *delegate;
```

How do I convert these two line in swift?

I searched the internet and tried to look into the library code so that I can get the hint, but didn't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use `protocol`:

```
var delegate: protocol<MyProtocol, MyAnotherProtocol>
```

For second one you can use just:

```
var delegate: MyProtocol
```

Comment: Second one is not completely of type `UIViewController` that implements `MyProtocol`. It is the reference of any class that implements `MyProtocol`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `protocol composition` to combine multiple protocols in single name as below.**

```
// Protocol Composition!!
typealias MyCompositeProtocol = protocol< MyProtocol, MyAnotherProtocol >
```

Then you can use the name `MyCompositeProtocol` instead of specifying multiple names.

like below,

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController, MyCompositeProtocol {
    var myDelegate : MyCompositeProtocol?
}
```